# why does ggvis layer_smooths can only appear as a first layer?

Tags: r, ggvis

If layer_smooths appears is the second layer added to ggvis plot (regardless of which is the first one), the data.table's variables are not recognised anymore, what's wrong with this layer?

```
library(ggvis)

> mtcars %>% 
+     ggvis(~mpg, ~hp) %>% 
+     layer_lines() %>%
+     layer_lines(~mpg, ~disp)

> mtcars %>% 
+     ggvis(~mpg, ~hp) %>% 
+     layer_lines() %>%
+     layer_smooths(~mpg, ~disp)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'mpg' not found

> mtcars %>% 
+     ggvis(~mpg, ~hp) %>% 
+     layer_smooths() %>%
+     layer_lines(~mpg, ~disp)

> mtcars %>% 
+     ggvis(~mpg, ~hp) %>% 
+     layer_smooths() %>%
+     layer_smooths(~mpg, ~disp)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'mpg' not found
```

Comment: I don't think the example makes a lot of sense. Can you explain what you are trying to do? Also, which version of ggvis are you using? I'm using 0.4.2 and I get a different error.

Comment: @lizzie
I am using also version 0.4.2 and i just copy - pasted my console. The same phenomenon persists after restart.
When layer_smooths is the second layer added to the plot, the variables are not recognized anymore. In particular, I can not plot two smooths on the same plot !!